# Unicode input Windows 8.1 Store App

Tags: c#, c++, unicode, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I want to receive the correct localized Unicode-Char if I press a key on the keyboard. (in a Windows 8.1 Store App with C++ or C#)

I'm currently receiving the keyboard input via `KeyEventArgs`-Event

C++:

```
Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^ window = Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();
window->KeyDown += ref new Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler<Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^, Windows::UI::Core::KeyEventArgs^>(this, &ComponentInterface::OnKeyDown);

void ComponentInterface::OnKeyDown(Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow^ window, Windows::UI::Core::KeyEventArgs^ e)
{
    unsigned int key = e->KeyStatus.ScanCode;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the character handle [CoreWindow::CharacterReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.characterreceived.aspx) rather than [CoreWindow::KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.keydown.aspx).

The KeyDown event provides just the key itself and doesn't include enough context on its own to know which character will ultimately be generated.